# Python code not running properly on Mac OS X (10.8) but works on Windows 7, why?

Tags: python, tkinter, popupmenu

I'm learing Python using the book "Introduction to Programming Using Python (Pearson 2013)". I use PyCharm 2.7 on my Mac OS X (10.8) to write Pyhon 3 code.

The following code (Create a GUI with tkinter and add a popup menu) does not run properly on my Mac OS X. The problem is that the popup menu doesn't show when pressing the right mouse click. I tested the code on my Windows 7 VM and in Windows 7 it works perfectly.

So my question is: why does the code work on Windows 7 but not on Mac OS X?

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *

class PopupMenuDemo:
    def __init__(self):
        window = Tk()
        window.title("Popup Menu Demo")

        # Create a popup menu
        self.menu = Menu(window, tearoff = 0)
        self.menu.add_command(label = "Draw a line", command = self.displayLine)
        self.menu.add_command(label = "Draw an oval", command = self.displayOval)
        self.menu.add_command(label = "Draw a rectangle", command = self.displayRectangle)
        self.menu.add_command(label = "Clear", command = self.clearCanvas)

        # Place canvas in window
        self.canvas = Canvas(window, width = 200, height = 100, bg = "white")
        self.canvas.pack()

        # Bind popup to canvas
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-3>", self.popup)

        window.mainloop()

    # Display a rectangle
    def displayRectangle(self):
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(10, 10, 190, 90, tags = "rectangle")

    def displayOval(self):
        self.canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 190, 90, tags = "oval")

    def displayLine(self):
        self.canvas.create_line(10, 10, 190, 90, tags = "line")
        self.canvas.create_line(10, 90, 190, 10, tags = "line")

    def clearCanvas(self):
        self.canvas.delete("rectangle", "oval", "line")

    def popup(self, event):
        self.menu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)

PopupMenuDemo()
```

Comment: The code seems to work when pressing "middle click". But that still leaves me with the question why it works with secondary click on windows and middle click in OS X?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution**

To make the code work properly in Mac OS X here's what has to be done.

Change:

```
self.canvas.bind("<Button-3>", self.popup)
```

To:

```
self.canvas.bind("<Button-2>", self.popup)
```

Button-3 is the middle click button while Button-2 is the secondary click button.

To make it work in Windows, use Button-3.